# Is the curve i get from a circle drawn on a paper rolled into a cylinder, after unrolling a cylindrical piece of paper, an ellipse?

Tags: geometry

Say I have a cylindrical can of beans. If I try to draw a 'circle' on the label of the can by using a compass and then flatten the label into a plane, will the 3D 'circle' originally on the cylinder  label become an ellipse. I tried to solve it using analytical geometry but it turned out to be somewhat difficult.  It sure looks like an ellipse but I got an expression for the semi-major axis that contains the arcsin function involving the radius of the compass and that of the cylindrical  can. Can anybody provide an intuitive answer please?

Comment: If the radius your compass is set to exceeds the diameter of the cylinder, the result will certainly not be an ellipse.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is down-voted or close-voted. It seems a reasonable question, although OP should probably include what their attempts to solve it using analytical geometry are, so that we can help assess it. ¶ What you're looking at is the intersection of a cylinder and a sphere centered on the surface of the cylinder; you then "unroll" the cylinder and ask about the shape of the resulting two-dimensional figure. I suspect the result *isn't* an ellipse after all, but I don't know offhand; I'd have to sit down and figure it out. In the meantime, kindly include your attempt?

Comment: **Sketch of approach.** Without loss of generality, let the cylinder be $x^2+y^2 = 1$ and the sphere be $(x-1)^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2, 0 < r < 1$. We then get $z^2 = r^2+2x-2$. To unroll, we let $x = \cos\theta$ and then we have $z^2 = r^2+2\cos\theta-2$ in the $\theta$-$z$ plane—not an ellipse.

Comment: Sorry, that should be $0 < r < 2$. Let's see if this [Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tgnzdqpijh) works.

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but it was the same thing BrianTung suggested. I'll leave this desmos demonstration to play with: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ojdpff7zec

Comment: I originally downvoted as I thought the wording was hand-wavy but now I understand the question better.

Comment: @Merosity The $x$ coordinate also needs to be scaled as $R_{can}$ changes. When $R_{can}$ is very large and $R_{sphere}$ is not, you should get approximately a circle. I inserted one factor of $R_{can}$ in your formula to make that happen: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ynncpreilu

Answer (score 5):

Brian Tung has the right idea in comments of representing the problem as a sphere-cylinder intersection – scaling the cylinder to have radius $1$ and the sphere representing the compass to radius $r$, the drawn curve when flattened has equation
$$y^2=r^2+2\cos x-2$$
which can be rearranged to
$$y^2+(2\sin x/2)^2=r^2$$
When $x$ is small, $2\sin x/2\sim x$ and the curve does *approximate* a circle, but it is never *exactly* an ellipse. When $r=2$ we get [Viviani's curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani%27s_curve), which provides intuition on why the curve deviates from ellipticity as $r$ increases: the intersection looks more like a helix.